# EOleSysError exception is raised in Windows10

Tags: com, windows-10, ihtmldocument2

In my application parse HTML document by using IHTMLDocument2, EOleSysError exception is raised during creating instance of IHTMLDocument2.
In few days ago, My application worked correctly.
 Are there anyone has information about the phenomenon like this ?

My OS is Windows10 (64bit).

Comment: I could resolve my issue by uninstalling KB3206632 ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4004227/windows-10-update-kb3206632 ). Now, Investigating why KB3206632 affects the my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer follow my comment.
Maybe Security policy about COM had been changed in [KB3206632](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4004227/windows-10-update-kb3206632).
I confirmed system log. Event ID 10016 was recorded. So I set appropriate permission by using "regedit.exe" and "dcomcnfg". And finally, My application has work correctly after re-install [KB3206632](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4004227/windows-10-update-kb3206632) .